# PHP/AJAX Requests: session_start(): Cannot send sesssion cache limiter - headers already sent

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, http-headers

I have a problem which I can not find a solution to:

After a mouse keypress (`onclick=""`) in my web application, I call a PHP function via AJAX request. This is nothing unusual. However, the PHP function needs to access some session variables.  As I call the PHP function via HTML5 `onclick` and AJAX request, the webpage is already rendered, which probably means the headers have already been sent.

Probably, as a result of that, I get the following error:

`session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent`

The key information here is that **my PHP function called through AJAX Request does not output anything to the browser before calling `session_start()`.**

Is there any solution to this, please? Originally, I thought, AJAX function calls are independent from rendering the webpage and I could basically call `session_start()` at any time via AJAX. But now, it looks to me, that I can not call `session_start()` from my PHP function if called with AJAX request, just because all the AJAX calls are performed after rendering the webpage and thus after sending the headers?

- Client Side: HTML5, JavaScript (no jquery)
- Server Side: PHP, MySQL

If you have any idea for a workaround, that would help. Because of security reasons, I do not want to pass needed parameters as POST arguments. Because of speed reasons, I do not want to access them from my MySQL database. I would really like to know, if there is a way to access session variables through AJAX calls.

What I would like to know, if it is possible to replace AJAX calls with local PHP function calls. Then, I could take advantage of PHP `global` variables.

Thank you.